# Is there a way to input values to a 2D array with O(n) time complexity?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

There is a very common method to input values to a 2D square matrix... using two for loops... Now is there a way to input values to a 2D array with O(n) time complexity?

Comment: When you say O(n), I suppose you mean n equals total size of the array. But you'll notice that when you do a O(n^2) the n^2 is actually the size of array, not just n. So its the same. We need at least a number of iterations equal to the size of array to fill it completely, which we already do in the nested loop approach.

Comment: Can there be an efficient version like storing the numbers in array of strings and then retrieving it using, say, Integer.parseInt().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first input method. For this you should search this on google and you will find one.

Sample link that I found:
[Fast input](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7394/help-on-fast-inputoutput)

But I think it wont effect much. Cause without 2 for loops, how can you store values on 2D array?

But, if you want to use only one for loop for your code. You can do a trick:

```
for(k=0;k<n*n;k++)
{
    i=k/n, j=k%n;
    scan(a[i][j]); // Here a is 2D array
}
```